# How to create structure for nested data set in golang?

Tags: go

New to golang & trying to make a script for making bulk upload to Elasticsearch server. My json data set is something like this...

```
{
    product_displayname: "LG Stylus 2 Plus K535D (16 GB, Brown)",
    product_price: "24000.00",
    popularity: "0.00",
    barcode: "",
    exclusive_flag: "0",
    product_id: "176982",
    product_name: "Stylus 2 Plus K535D (Brown)",
    brand_name: "LG",
    brand_id: "1",
    product_spec : {
        display_spec: [{
            spec_id: "103",
            sdv: "24000",
            snv: "24000.0000"
        }, {
            spec_id: "104",
            sdv: "GSM",
            snv: "0.0000"
        }],
        filter_spec: [{
            spec_id: "103",
            sdv: "24000",
            snv: "24000.0000"
        }, {
            spec_id: "105",
            sdv: "Touch Screen",
            snv: "0.0000"
        }]
    }
}
```

Golang Structure I made(by refering google & other online info) for the above dataset is like this...

```
type Product struct {
    product_displayname string `json:"product_displayname"`
    product_price       string `json:"product_price"`
    popularity          string `json:"popularity"`
    barcode             string `json:"barcode"`
    exclusive_flag      string `json:"exclusive_flag"`
    product_id          string `json:"product_id"`
    product_name        string `json:"product_name"`
    brand_name          string `json:"brand_name"`
    brand_id            string `json:"brand_id"`
    product_spec
}

type product_spec struct {
    display_spec []display_speclist
    filter_spec []filter_speclist
}

type display_speclist struct {
    spec_id string `json:"spec_id"`
    sdv     string `json:"sdv"`
    snv     string `json:"snv"`
}

type filter_speclist struct {
    spec_id string `json:"spec_id"`
    sdv     string `json:"sdv"`
    snv     string `json:"snv"`
}
```

But, whenever I'm trying to use above Structure with sample data in my bulk upload script I'm getting following error

```
github.com/crazyheart/elastic-bulk-upload/main.go:70: syntax error: missing operand
github.com/crazyheart/elastic-bulk-upload/main.go:70: unknown escape sequence
github.com/crazyheart/elastic-bulk-upload/main.go:71: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

I feel like I'm making some mistake in mapping that nested field `display_spec & filter_spec` in golang structure. But can't able to figure out what it is.

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5"
    "strconv"
)

type Product struct {
    ProductDisplayname string `json:"product_displayname"`
    ProductPrice string `json:"product_price"`
    Popularity string `json:"popularity"`
    Barcode string `json:"barcode"`
    ExclusiveFlag string `json:"exclusive_flag"`
    ProductID string `json:"product_id"`
    ProductName string `json:"product_name"`
    BrandName string `json:"brand_name"`
    BrandID string `json:"brand_id"`
    ProductSpec struct {
        DisplaySpec []struct {
            SpecID string `json:"spec_id"`
            Sdv string `json:"sdv"`
            Snv string `json:"snv"`
        } `json:"display_spec"`
        FilterSpec []struct {
            SpecID string `json:"spec_id"`
            Sdv string `json:"sdv"`
            Snv string `json:"snv"`
        } `json:"filter_spec"`
    } `json:"product_spec"`
}

func main() {
    // Create a context
    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := elastic.NewClient()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("%v", err)
    }

    // Bulk upload code
    n := 0
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        bulkRequest := client.Bulk()
        for j := 0; j < 10000; j++ {
            n++
            product_data := Product{product_displayname:"LG Stylus 2 Plus K535D (16 GB, Brown)",product_price:"24000.00",popularity:"0.00",barcode:"",exclusive_flag:"0",product_id:"17698276",product_name:"Stylus 2 Plus K535D (Brown)",brand_name:"LG",brand_id:"1",product_spec:{display_spec:[{spec_id:"103",sdv:"24000",snv:"24000.0000"},{spec_id:"104",sdv:"GSM",snv:"0.0000"}],filter_spec:[{spec_id:"103",sdv:"24000",snv:"24000.0000"},{spec_id:"105",sdv:"Touch Screen",snv:"0.0000"}]} }
            req := elastic.NewBulkIndexRequest().Index("shopfront").Type("products").Id(strconv.Itoa(n)).Doc(product_data)
            bulkRequest = bulkRequest.Add(req)
        }

        bulkResponse, err := bulkRequest.Do(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        if bulkResponse != nil {
            fmt.Println(bulkResponse)
        }
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Workflow**

1.- Validate your [json](http://jsonlint.com/) (the one you posted is invalid).

2.- Build a proper `struct`, you can help yourself using this nice [tool](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/).

**For your case**

The `structs` appears to be fine except you're not exporting the struct fields by capitalizing the initial letter (Thanks @ANisus).

This (shorted) seems more *natural*.

```
type Product struct {
    ProductDisplayname string `json:"product_displayname"`
    ProductSpec struct {
        DisplaySpec []struct {
            SpecID string `json:"spec_id"`
            Sdv string `json:"sdv"`
            Snv string `json:"snv"`
        } `json:"display_spec"`
        FilterSpec []struct {
            SpecID string `json:"spec_id"`
            Sdv string `json:"sdv"`
            Snv string `json:"snv"`
        } `json:"filter_spec"`
    } `json:"product_spec"`
}
```

Comment: In addition, he performs the common Go beginner's mistake of not exporting the struct fields by capitalizing the initial letter. But that _is_ a nice tool!

Comment: Any yet another thing: If that is the "json" he is using, it is invalid. JSON objects keys must be wrapped in quotes: `"barcode"` instead of `barcode`

Comment: Thanks again @ANisus  incorporated to the answer.

Comment: @ANisus : Actually, I'm using  ```https://github.com/olivere/elastic``` for communicating with Elasticsearch & where one example at there given like this ```tweet := Tweet{User: "olivere", Message: "Package strconv implements conversions to and from string representations of basic data types. " + strconv.Itoa(n)}``` . That's why I've just strip down those quotes from my JSON string.

Comment: @klashxx I've posted my main go file ```main.go```. Can you please look at it & tell me what could be the problem.